# How to parse a table that has spaces and blanks to a structure/tokenize?

Tags: bash

I have to parse a table into an array or tokenize but retain the position e.g.,:

```
$cat t.txt

ID  Name         Callin  Link Auth  CCOS Msg   Channel Priv Limit
1                    false   false      true       USER
2   Administrator    false   false      true       ADMINISTRATOR
```

'USER' should have the field value of 6 instead most of the code gives me as 5 even with field seperator as tab

I have trouble with the blank fields. How do I effectively add it to an array

code that I tried , all of them skips the blank value and doesnt capture it:

```
while read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
do
    echo "Col1 : $col1"
    echo "Col2 : $col2"
    echo "Col3 : $col3"
    echo "Col4 : $col4"
    echo "Col5 : $col5"
    echo "Col6 : $col6"
done < t.txt
```

---

```
cat t.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[ \t]+" } ; { print $1 "\t" $6}'
```

Ideally, I want the field printed like

```
echo field[0], field[6] # 1 , USER and 2, ADMINISTRATOR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed -e 's/^\([0-9]*\)\s.*\s\([^ ]*\)$/\1,\2/g'  < t.txt
ID  Name         Callin  Link Auth  CCOS Msg   Channel Priv Limit
1,USER
2,ADMINISTRATOR
```

Comment: Anyway to skip the header ?

Comment: `sed -e '1{h;d}'  -e...`

Comment: what does h;d mean

Answer (score 3):

If your file really has tab delimiters, awk will parse it correctly.  If it has spaces only, GNU awk can parse on fixed-width boundaries.  If neither, you'll have to preprocess it somehow; you can't parse on what's not there.

Taking your data, I added tab delimiters.  I looked for any two-space string followed by a non-space, and handled the first data line specially:

```
$ sed -E 's/  ([^ ])/\t\1/g; s/^1/1\t/;' fixed.dat  | cat -vt
ID^IName       ^ICallin^ILink Auth^ICCOS Msg ^IChannel Priv Limit
1^I                  ^Ifalse ^Ifalse    ^Itrue     ^IUSER
2 ^IAdministrator  ^Ifalse ^Ifalse    ^Itrue     ^IADMINISTRATOR
```

That can be parsed just find with awk:

```
$ sed -E 's/  ([^ ])/\t\1/g; s/^1/1\t/;' fixed.dat  | awk -F\\t '{print $6}'
Channel Priv Limit
USER
ADMINISTRATOR
```

To use fixed-width columns in GNU awk, set up the FIELDWIDTHS string.  Here, it's done programmatically:

```
BEGIN {
    titles = "ID  Name         Callin  Link Auth  CCOS-Msg   Channel-Priv-Limit"

    pos = 1
    sep = ""
    while( match(substr(titles, pos), / +/) > 0 ) {
    pos += RSTART + RLENGTH - 1
    FIELDWIDTHS = FIELDWIDTHS sep  RSTART + RLENGTH - 1
    sep = " " 
    }
    FIELDWIDTHS = FIELDWIDTHS sep length(titles) - pos

    print "FIELDWIDTHS:", FIELDWIDTHS
}

{
    OFS = "|"

    print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9
}
```

result:

```
$ awk -f fixed.awk fixed.dat
FIELDWIDTHS: 4 13 8 5 6 11 17
ID  |Name         |Callin  |Link |Auth  |CCOS Msg   |Channel Priv Limi||
1   |             |    fals|e   f|alse  |    true   |    USER||
2   |Administrator|    fals|e   f|alse  |    true   |    ADMINISTRATOR||
```

That's a little wrong because it uses the title line to compute the column offsets, and your titles don't line up over your data.  But if this is your situation, you can see your way to fixing up the FIELDWIDTHS string to parse your columns.

If you're not sure what's wrong with a given line, my favorite way to examine the line is a little complicated, but very fast and indestructible:

```
$ sed -E 's/  ([^ ])/\t\1/g; s/^1/1\t/;' fixed.dat | 
  sed -ne '2 {p;q;}' | tr \\t \\n | nl -ba
 1  1
 2                    
 3  false 
 4  false    
 5  true     
 6  USER
```

**sed**(1) choses the line to print (and quits, much faster if the file is big).  **tr**(1) converts the delimiter to a newline, and **nl**(1) numbers the lines, so you know which field is which.  If the line is missing a tab, it shows up quick:

```
$ sed -E 's/  ([^ ])/\t\1/g' fixed.dat  | sed -ne '2 {p;q;}' | tr \\t \\n | nl -ba
 1  1                  
 2  false 
 3  false    
 4  true     
 5  USER
```

My final piece of advice, if I may: don't use the shell to parse files.  Besides being designed especially for parsing, **awk** is much faster because 1) loops are not interpreted and, 2) the script executes as a single process.  If you're looping in the shell over anything that isn't a list of filenames, you're working too hard.